# Show Git Log Details Past Certain Date

Tags: git

I've been working on an open-source project for the past 2 months.

So far I've fixed a bunch of bugs, and I'd like to send out my diffs for a code review. I've only committed my changes locally, rather than doing a "`git push origin`."

I used "`git log -p *`" to show all of my changes, but I'd prefer to only see changes past a certain date.

Is there a particular "git" command that will show all diffs only after a certain date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log -p --after=<date>
git log -p --after=2012-09-01
git log -p --after="2 months ago"
```

Answer (score 1):

`git log --since="datestring"` will do. But if you are preparing patches for upstream, `git format-patch <commit-ish>..`  would be more normal. Check your projects contribution policy.